# KeyError: 'screen_name' in Scraping Data Off Twitter Using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, twitter, keyerror, traceback

I have an key error when running this code when running in jupyter notebook. Jupyter Notebook can't traceback the 'screen_name' when I run a research by **scraping** Twitter.

Here is the environment that I use for my code.

```
import spacy
pip install twitterscraper    
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re  
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load(r'C:\Users\tnguy\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\en_core_web_sm-3.0.0')
```

Then, I run this code, Jupyter Notebook can't find traceback and return the value for 'screen name' by searching the user name.

```
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
from twitterscraper.query import query_tweets_from_user
import datetime as dt 
import pandas as pd 


begin_date = dt.date(2020,7,1)
end_date = dt.date(2020,7,13)


limit = 100
lang = 'english'

#Use this to search a specific user

user = 'realDonaldTrump'
tweets = query_tweets_from_user(user)
df = pd.DataFrame(t.__dict__ for t in tweets)

df = df.loc[df['screen_name'] == user]

df = df['text']

df
```

**It shows a key error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'screen_name'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-bf2a4d782174> in <module>
     18 df = pd.DataFrame(t.__dict__ for t in tweets)
     19 
---> 20 df = df.loc[df['screen_name'] == user]
     21 
     22 df = df['text']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'screen_name'
```